# Spring JPA Query problem using 'in' operator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

In Spring Intreface I have following code:

```
@Query("select gl from GroupEntity gl where ?1 in gl.contacts ")
List<GroupEntity> findGroupsByContact(ContactEntity contactEntity);
```

and want to find all Group with contains a Contact, but IntelliJ idea shows error after where condition ( ?1 in gl.contacts) and shows this error:

```
'(' or <input parameter> expected, got 'gl'
```

what is the solution?

related parts of Entities are:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contactGroup")
public class GroupEntity {
...
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ContactEntity> contacts;
...
}
```

but in ContactEntity did not use @ManyToMany for GroupEntity(Is it the root of the problem?)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class ContactEntity {
...
}
```

Comment: please show entity and Repository why create query when repository methods are ez and available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the `in` JPQL operator when the entity attribute is the right operant.

You should use `member of` instead.
"Member of" should be used when you provide a value to the query in order to check if it belongs to some collection in your entity.
"In" should be used when you provide a list of values to the query in order to check if a property in your entity belong to this list.

Examples:

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {

@Id
private String id;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<EntityB> entities;

}
```

JPQL:

```
SELECT a FROM EntityA a WHERE a.id IN :ids

SELECT a FROM EntityA a WHERE :b MEMBER OF a.entities
```

Answer (score 2):

If the relationships are established properly then you can query Groups from Contact repository.

**Group.java**

```
  @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "group", orphanRemoval = true)
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
```

**Contact.java**

```
@ManyToOne
Group group;
```

Comment: OP wants to is a single `contactEntity` is in the list `contact` of group. Your answer is not relevant with what OP wants.

Comment: Answers need not be direct to the point. It's about sharing the right approahc and what works in projects that implement JPA in production.

Comment: First of all your solution is wrong, did you test it ? And the second OP don't want to find a list of ids, OP wants groups those having a specific `contactEntity`. Please read the post again.

Comment: That's answered in the second part of my answer. Why do you think that's wrong?  If ManyToMany relationship defined then what's the confusion in querying groups? Anyway for clarity I'm editing and removing my first part.